# Azure The 'resourceTargetId' property of endpoint 'vm1-TF' is invalid or missing

Tags: azure, terraform

I want to implement traffic manager in Terraform between two vm's from different locations (West Europe and North Europe). I attach my code, but I don't know how to configure "target_resource_id" for each vm, because the vm's were created in a for loop, also the networks. The traffic manager would switch to the secondary vm, in case of failure of the first vm. Any ideas?

My code:

```
variable "subscription_id" {}
variable "tenant_id" {}
variable "environment" {}
variable "azurerm_resource_group_name" {}
variable "locations" {
  type = map(string)
  default = {
    vm1 = "North Europe"
    vm2 = "West Europe"
  }
}

# Configure the Azure Provider
provider "azurerm" {
  subscription_id = var.subscription_id
  tenant_id       = var.tenant_id
  version = "=2.10.0"
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "main" {
  for_each            = var.locations
  name                = "${each.key}-network"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = each.value
  resource_group_name = var.azurerm_resource_group_name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "internal" {
  for_each             = var.locations
  name                 = "${each.key}-subnet"
  resource_group_name  = var.azurerm_resource_group_name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.main[each.key].name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.2.0/24"]
}

resource "azurerm_public_ip" "example" {
  for_each                = var.locations
  name                    = "${each.key}-pip"
  location                = each.value
  resource_group_name     = var.azurerm_resource_group_name
  allocation_method       = "Static"
  idle_timeout_in_minutes = 30

  tags = {
    environment = "dev01"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "main" {
  for_each            = var.locations
  name                = "${each.key}-nic"
  location            = each.value
  resource_group_name = var.azurerm_resource_group_name

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "testconfiguration1"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.internal[each.key].id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
    public_ip_address_id          = azurerm_public_ip.example[each.key].id
  }
}

resource "random_password" "password" {
  length = 16
  special = true
  override_special = "_%@"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "main" {
  for_each              = var.locations
  name                  = "${each.key}t-vm"
  location              = each.value
  resource_group_name   = var.azurerm_resource_group_name
  network_interface_ids = [azurerm_network_interface.main[each.key].id]
  vm_size               = "Standard_D2s_v3"


  storage_image_reference {
    publisher = "Canonical"
    offer     = "UbuntuServer"
    sku       = "18.04-LTS"
    version   = "latest"
  }
  storage_os_disk {
    name              = "${each.key}-myosdisk1"
    caching           = "ReadWrite"
    create_option     = "FromImage"
    managed_disk_type = "Standard_LRS"
  }
  os_profile {
    computer_name  = "${each.key}-hostname"
    admin_username = "testadmin"
    admin_password = random_password.password.result
  }
  os_profile_linux_config {
    disable_password_authentication = false
  }
  tags = {
    environment = "dev01"
  }

}

resource "random_id" "server" {
  keepers = {
    azi_id = 1
  }

  byte_length = 8
}

resource "azurerm_traffic_manager_profile" "example" {
  name                   = random_id.server.hex
  resource_group_name    = var.azurerm_resource_group_name
  traffic_routing_method = "Priority"

  dns_config {
    relative_name = random_id.server.hex
    ttl           = 100
  }

  monitor_config {
    protocol                     = "http"
    port                         = 80
    path                         = "/"
    interval_in_seconds          = 30
    timeout_in_seconds           = 9
    tolerated_number_of_failures = 3
  }

  tags = {
    environment = "dev01"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_traffic_manager_endpoint" "first-vm" {
  for_each            = var.locations
  name                = "${each.key}-TF"
  resource_group_name = var.azurerm_resource_group_name
  profile_name        = "${azurerm_traffic_manager_profile.example.name}"
  target_resource_id  = "[azurerm_network_interface.main[each.key].id]"
  type                = "azureEndpoints"
  priority              = "${[each.key] == "vm1" ? 1 : 2}"
}
```

My error:

```
Error: trafficmanager.EndpointsClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. 
Status=400 Code="BadRequest" Message="The 'resourceTargetId' property of endpoint 'vm1-TF' is invalid or missing. 
The property must be specified only for the following endpoint types: AzureEndpoints, NestedEndpoints. 
You must have read access to the resource to which it refers."
```

Comment: You can look at this example: https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/tree/master/examples/traffic-manager/virtual-machine

Comment: I used this example in order to configure this one, but I don t know how should I set target_resource_id in my example

Comment: Inappropriate value for attribute "target_resource_id": string required.

Comment: yes that's what I thought, string is required!

Comment: do you know how should it be configured?

Comment: If the answer below could solve your question, you should accept the reply, look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). then other communities will benefit from it and also other people would like to give a answer to your question.

Comment: @KrochVolt Hi, Were you able to solve your problem? Please mark it as answer so that it can be helpful to others also. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

According to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-endpoint-types):

Azure endpoints are used for Azure-based services in Traffic Manager. The following Azure resource types are supported:

1. PaaS cloud services
2. Web Apps
3. Web App Slots
4. PublicIPAddress resources (which can be connected to VMs either directly or via an Azure Load Balancer). The publicIpAddress must have a DNS name assigned to be used in a Traffic Manager profile.

In your code, you need to change the **Target ResourceId** to **PublicIPAddress**. You should not pass the Network Interface ID.

```
resource "azurerm_traffic_manager_endpoint" "first-vm" {
  for_each            = var.locations
  name                = "${each.key}-TF"
  resource_group_name = var.azurerm_resource_group_name
  profile_name        = "${azurerm_traffic_manager_profile.example.name}"
  target_resource_id  = azurerm_public_ip.example[each.key].id
  type                = "azureEndpoints"
  priority              = "${[each.key] == "vm1" ? 1 : 2}"
}
```

Please Note: The publicIpAddress must have a DNS name assigned to be used in a Traffic Manager profile.

Also you can check this [ARM Template](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/201-traffic-manager-vm/azuredeploy.json) which is equivalent to this terraform template.

Hope this helps!